# Intelligence and Poor Performance

Tags: learning

I hope this is a valid question for this forum.

Is there any learning disability related to a person being intelligent but having great difficulty expressing themselves especially on written exams or writing a homework piece multiples times still with errors despite having a solid understanding of the material?

I've heard people say things like "you must not really understand it if you didn't get it correctly" or similar. I feel that is a reduction of a much bigger issue.

In my experience, I am a mathematics major, and mathematics is a  field of study that takes some serious dedication. I spend a lot of time working on understanding the concepts. I'm a very dedicated student and I am close to finishing my undergrad. I understand the concepts quite well, I don't get stumped by a new idea very often. I can honestly say I understand the material I cover very well. However, I have difficulty often getting my ideas down on paper. When I have homework to do I end up writing the homework 5 or 6 times and there's still errors present--I don't rush through either, I spend a lot of time working on the problems. When it comes to an exam, it gets worse because now I have the pressure of a time constraint. It's incredibly frustrating knowing the concepts and seeing the connections, ideas and required methods to prove some mathematical statement and not being able to express it properly.

Thanks.

Comment: From my own experience and observations, it is true that intelligent people often need more time to complete some task. And vice versa, not intelligent are often hectic at giving an answer, even if they do not understand the problem. Another side issue of high intelligence is the perfectionism, which obviously adds more performance issues by solving a task, but still some tasks definitely need some grade of perfectionism, so it can be useful sometimes.